# How to create a form layout interface using kivy framework with Python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a form layout with kivy that will have multiple user input fields and labels for each user input fields and some fields with checkboxes/radio buttons. How do I get started with creating a form layout in kivy & then adjust the position of each fields/widgets? Also which form layout should I choose?

Comment: you could use a box layout or a grid layout for that

Comment: @VanshSachdeva When I use BoxLayout or GridLayout all the form labels and text input spaces are closely attached to each other either horizontally or vertically. I cant get proper spacing or proper organized structure for all the form fields & the layout gets messy.

Comment: share your code